# Handling parallelization

Tags: snakemake

I'm a bit new on snakemake.

Imagine that I have a rule, like the one below (I've set the number of threads to 10).

Is there any way to make `snakemake` magically handles the parallelization of the loop for in this rule?

```
rule MY_RULE:
    input:
        input_file=TRAIN_DATA
    output:
        output_file=OUTPUT_DATA
    threads: 10
    run:        
        for f,o in zip(input.input_file, output.output_file):
            DO_SOMETHING_AND_SAVE(f,o)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess your rule could be re-written as (with additional code to make a small self-contained example):

```
TRAIN_DATA = ['a.txt', 'b.txt', 'c.txt']
OUTPUT_DATA = ['a.out', 'b.out', 'c.out']

files= dict(zip(OUTPUT_DATA, TRAIN_DATA))

wildcard_constraints:
    x= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in OUTPUT_DATA])

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{x}', x= OUTPUT_DATA),

rule MY_RULE:
    input:
        input_file= lambda wc: files[wc.x]
    output:
        output_file= '{x}'
    run:        
        DO_SOMETHING_AND_SAVE(input.input_file, output.output_file)
```

This will run rule MY_RULE for each input/output pair in parallel. Of course, the details depend on what exactly you want to do before and after MY_RULE...

Comment: That's correct, but the question was about parallelization.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer,
I've tried to run you exactly your example without success.

I got the following exception:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
WorkflowError:
Target rules may not contain wildcards. Please specify concrete files or a rule without wildcards.
```

To reproduce it I created fake `[a,b,c].txt` files and a function DO_SOMETHING_AND_SAVE.

Comment: @TiagoFreitasPereira - Can you show how you are executing snakemake? You get that error if you execute it as `snakemake [some options] MY_RULE` instead of just `snakemake [some options]`. As the error says, the final (target) rule cannot contain wildcards.

Comment: Yes, you got it right. This was exactly the problem I was having.
Now it works and in parallel :-)

I have another question. Is it straight forward to run this "parallel" rule in a SGE grid?
My plan is to run this rule as a job array e.g `qsub -t 10 .......` (I'm doing an exploratory analysis on snakemake for my research).

Thanks.

Comment: @TiagoFreitasPereira Yes- it is straightforward to run it on a cluster (it's one of the great things of snakemake), see [cluster-execution](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#cluster-execution). The simplest would be `snakemake --cluster "qsub -t 10 ..." -j <num of jobs you want to submit at the same time>`. I'm not sure about snakemake and job arrays as I haven't used them much but try to google it or submit it as another question.